Problem while installing express on termux
I tried installing express using termux,
npm install express
But it gave these error
npm error code EACCES
npm error syscall symlink
npm error path ../mime/cli.js
npm error dest /storage/emulated/0/PROJECTS/express-blog/node_modules/.bin/mime
npm error errno -13
npm error Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/storage/emulated/0/PROJECTS/express-blog/node_modules/.bin/mime'
npm error     at async symlink (node:internal/fs/promises:1001:10)
npm error     at async Promise.all (index 0)
npm error     at async Promise.all (index 0)
npm error     at async #createBinLinks (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/rebuild.js:394:5)
npm error     at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
npm error     at async #linkAllBins (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/rebuild.js:375:5)
npm error     at async #build (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/rebuild.js:160:7)
npm error     at async Arborist.rebuild (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/rebuild.js:62:5)
npm error     at async [reifyPackages] (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:325:11)
npm error     at async Arborist.reify (/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:142:5) {
npm error   errno: -13,
npm error   code: 'EACCES',
npm error   syscall: 'symlink',
npm error   path: '../mime/cli.js',
npm error   dest: '/storage/emulated/0/PROJECTS/express-blog/node_modules/.bin/mime'
npm error }
npm error
npm error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm error It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm error
npm error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the npm error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm error the command again as root/Administrator.

I had also installed other modules such as mongoose, body-parser and nodemon but there was no problem
Please help!
I tried installing express on termux but it gave an error
Npm error this operation was rejected by your operating system
Even though I had installed other modules using the same process

The path /storage/emulated/0 is the shared storage of Android which is mounted in a special way which applies some restrictions like no sym links, no executables and so on.  Thus you are using the wrong path for what you want to do.

Please what path am I supposed to use?

something below /data/data/com.termux/files/ should work.
